# Indentation inside of text

Tags: sectioning, indentation, sections-paragraphs

I know that the title of this question might be a little bit confusing, but I don't know how can I solve my problem and even how to search for the solution.
I want to make inside a long text something what looks like:

```
Title
  Some text
Title2
  Some text
```

But I don't want to break the whole text using section or subsection comment. And I am looking for a solution more elegant that normal tab before 'Some text'. Even the enumerate or itemize environment is not what I am looking for. 
I just want to make `Title` as a bold text and in the next line have some text.

Comment: What about `Title \par \hspace*{2em} Some text \par Title2 \par \hspace*{2em} Some more text`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, or some variant, may solve your problem. It's not clear what you want when the text wraps to a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
\addvspace{0.2cm}% perhaps, as Barbara Beeton suggests
\textbf{#1}
\par
\hspace{0.5cm}
}
\begin{document}

\mytitle{Title}
\lipsum[15]

\mytitle{Another title}
More text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :)

Comment: when the text in an "early" paragraph occupies more than one line, there really isn't a great deal of contrast to make the next title stand out.  this would be even less obvious if the last line of the paragraph is full or nearly so.  some `\addvpace` before the title could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

If only parindent is positive:

\def\zhiva#1{\noindent\textbf{#1}\par}

\zhiva{Title1} My paragraph.

\zhiva{Title1} My paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can see, that in a dual answer there is an opposite vision of indenting and non-indenting.